# How do width, height and resolution matter in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, retina

How do width, height and resolution matter, and what's the standard or how to calculate the right resolution for current width and height in order to achieve a well refined image or retina image, or an image that is not pixelated?

I want to make some images that are very good quality like an android icon, a game character, and a wallpaper. But I don't know if there are any standards on deciding the size. References and cheat sheets would be a great help. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only width and height in pixels matter. Resolution is an metadata instruction for converting pixels to physical units when printing.

Comment: ...even if you add retina to the mix?

Comment: @Bakabaka yes it is a css trick the net optimized pipeline has no place for resolution data, optimizers frequently strip this info off.

Comment: see related question http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create