# How do I please use a given resolution to design under Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, resolution, interface-design

I have never done an app interface design before.

I got this freelance work where I have to design the visual interface for an app working under Windows. My client says his ultimate device would be the Surface 3. He insisted on the fact that the resolution should be high enough for the visuals to be clear on a larger screen.

I went under Windows website to get the Surface 3's screen dimensions and the resolution given there was 1920x1280. 
I had previously done my graphics (which were approved by client) under Illustrator, and I thought, if I have to deal with resolutions, then I should probably take my work icon by icon to Photoshop.

1. How do I please make sure that my work's resolution is going to be good enough both for the Surface 3 screen and other screens?
2. How do I please go about the resolution(1920x1280) under Photoshop? I have created a rectangle of 9"x 6" which fits on an A4 document leaving a border of +/- 3cm, and my document is set to 300pixels/inch
3. I guess I have to do more than one instance for each icon, for different screens. Would 3 different instances(low/med/high) be enough? How do I please make them different (dimensions wise).

My client seems to think I know what I am doing, and I do not want to sound like I do not at all. 
Please bear with me.. So far I have only done graphics related work and was never ever involved in anything else.

Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Hi ini, there is a lot of information on the web about creating responsive designs for multiple screen sizes. For 2 & 3 I would read this thread [is it mandatory to keep 72 dpi for web design? What if I create in 200dpi?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create-in-200dpi)

Comment: There's a lot of questions here beyond the three you've posted. It may be best to narrow this down to targeted, *specific* areas rather than asking for the whole kit and kaboodle in one question. There are books and tutorials out there dedicated to answering much of this.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, take a new document. Use Pixels as Units. Use the 1920x1080 as your document size.