# how to convert PT to Px in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have to convert text format pt to px any Document setting or by how can i change pt to px format for the text[image: Chane pt to px]

Comment: You can change this unit from settings, or just type XX px

Comment: In Adobe software, 1 pixel is **equal to** 1 point. For text sizes, there's no need to change it.

Comment: Hum... The pt -> px size is resolution-dependent. A 6 pt text at 72 ppi is smaller than a 6 pt text at 300 ppi in pixel size.

Comment: Not really. 6pt is 6pt. The *print* size of varying ppi documents is different, but the type sizes aren't. [See Here.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create-in-200dpi/13780#13780)

Comment: @SOIA. That is not true on the web. 6pt is like 60% larger than 6px. See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/p2ptw084/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Go to `Edit > Preference > Unit & Rulers` and change type points to pixels

Answer (score 1):

You also can right click into text input and select unit. This is good if you want change value only for one property and keep units in other fields.

Or you can simply rewrite "pt" to "px"

Fastest way to unit settings is doubleclick on ruler.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

First Open Photoshop,[image] Go to Edit Menu > scroll down click Preference > Unit & Rulers and change type points to pixels

[image]

Comment: This was already answered four years ago with the exact same answer you gave. Please don't necro-bump posts with duplicate answers.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a great pt to px converter. http://pttopx.com/

1 px = 0.75 point; 1 point = 1.333333 px

Comment: Please explain you link-only-answer better!  Suppose the given link is broken your given answer now is useless. Add a solution by your own words, then the link can be a reference ...

Comment: 1 pt = 1/72 inches. Size of 1 px depends on what your document PPI  is set to. And this boys and girls is why we set documents that are meant for digital only consumption to 72 PPI ad then we get one pixel = 1 point which is convenient due to the underlying math engine.