# How to make clear images of thumbnails when they are enlarged on the web?

Tags: images

What is the best format to use to make clean looking thumbnails when they are enlarged on the web?

Comment: You can not. It is the other way. From a good picture you do the miniature.

Answer (score 2):

Thumbnails on the web are **not** the original image. Or at least they shouldn't be. You do **not** "enlarge" thumbnails to create full version images. You work the other way around.

Start with a large higher resolution image, then crop or resize to create the thumbnail image.

**You should always work high quality to low quality**, not the other way around.

Answer (score -2):

Images will always be constrained to pixels per inch, so it is important to take into consideration screen sizes to screen resolution in determining how large your images will appear on various devices and the quality they will be displayed at.

- High definition: 600 pixels per inch (ppi)
  Standard definition: 300ppi
  Medium-Low res: 150ppi
  Low res: 72ppi

Comment: Web images do *not* use PPI. See here:  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create-in-200dpi/13780#13780

Comment: No... they do. Because the eyes can see a limited number of pixels per inch. Thanks for -1ing an answer I gave him that is way better than one you could. Compare 72ppi vs 300ppi in a Google image search result and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Nope.. read the link I posted. You are incorrect.

Comment: Dude people like you disgust me and make this place a ghosttown. People like me walk away and don't post. A 10" Screen width that is 1000x800 pixels will display a 100x100px image as 1". It will display the image as 100pixels per inch. I read the thread you linked. YOU READ IT BACKWARDS. A 100pixel image won't always display as 1".

Comment: You should read a bit more carefully. I **wrote** that so it's exceptionally unlikely that "I read it backwards." seeing as it's my post to begin with. *Nowhere* does it say anything about 1". Clearly you read incorrectly. And any personal attacks are pretty unwarranted. *Professionals* should be able to *discuss* matters without getting so riled up.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer. Please, as @Scott says, keep things civil. We encourage discussion, heated, if needed, but please keep it nice. We're all here to help each other. Thanks!