# 300 dpi image for website and size less

Tags: image-quality

how to reduce the size of image size keeping resolution as 300 DPI for web banners in Adobe Photoshop? Is there any other software better than adobe photoshop?

i have tried but either the size become bigger or if I decrease resolution image quality becomes lower.

please get me a solution.

Best regards,
Bijesh Babu

Comment: DPI doesn't matter for web images width and height... You should check out [is it mandatory to keep 72 dpi for web design? What if I create in 200dpi?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create-in-200dpi)

Comment: There are actually two questions here. one regarding dpi and one regarding interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need high Dpi for web. 72 ppi and what ever size should be enough to make it sharp detailed image for web. You need 200 ppi or more only if you want to print the picture sharp. Size of file increase w/ length, width and hugely with dpi. 
You can choose size of pics by first cropping size you want. Then chose option **save for web** it would allow you to check for sharpness and size of file in Photoshop . 
GL

Comment: 72DPI is as irrelevant as 300DPI for on-screen graphics. Ignore it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Web graphics in general are fixed in pixel dimensions. As such, completely ignore the DPI setting.

If you are asked to provide a 600px wide banner, simply make your image 600px wide. (the exception is if you also need to support high density screens. For example, an iPhone 5 may also require a 1200px wide version of that same graphic).

How to compress graphics is a broad topic, but, in general:

- if it's flat art, GIF or PNG are typically better
- if it's photographic in nature, JPG is better

You can shrink GIFs further by reducing the color pallet. You can shrink PNGs further by using various PNG compression tools (one common one is ImageOptim). You can reduce JPGs file sizes by changing the amount of JPG compression.

Beyond that, you need to show us the image for us to make specific suggestions.