# Resizing image to real world dimensions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize

this may sound like a really amateur question but I'm trying to resize some images to dimensions in centimetres (10cm height x 15cm width to give you an idea), but upon changing two photos to the same centimetre dimensions, I notice they have completely different pixel dimensions? Am I doing it wrong or is this meant to be this way. Thanks

Comment: Are you `Resampling` when you change dimensions?

Comment: Yes, as I can't achieve 10x15cm when I uncheck resample because it automatically changes the sizes based on whatever I put in

Comment: You can print an image at a certain size, and an image can have a certain number of pixels. If your images have different pixel dimensions at the same physical size it simply means that one image contains fewer pixel in the first place.

Comment: Is the resolution the same between the images?

Answer (score 1):

Simple ratio: PPI = Pixels per inch

Same centimeters with different number of pixels mean different densities of said pixels. The denser the pixels, the highest the quality (resolution). So one of your images might be 72ppi while the other might be 300ppi.

Comment: One image resized to 10x15 turns out like this http://prntscr.com/7yxa08 - the other turns out like this: http://prntscr.com/7yxanl

Comment: I specified 72 PPI on both images when resizing, yet they still have different dimensions in pixels, will they both print 10x15cm ?

Answer (score 0):

First understand that `resolution + width + height = Print size`.

You can't change the left side of the equation and expect the right side to stay the same. From the sound of things you are trying to alter the width, height, *and* resolution but retain the print size. That's why you are struggling.

If you are **not** printing these images, the `resolution` field means **nothing**. [**See Here**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create-in-200dpi)

If you **are** intending to print these images, then you want a minimum of 240PPI in the resolution field and you do **not** want to `Resample` when changing the width and height. This **often** means you get a width and height (print size) which is different than you anticipate.

When you uncheck the `Resample` option and subsequently alter the `Resolution` of an image, Photoshop does *not* generate new pixels ([interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)). It merely changes the *density of the existing pixels* in the image. This is done to keep the image quality the same. However, in order to do this the width and height ***must*** change to match the new pixel density of the image.

You can do what you are trying to do. However, it is **not** recommended for print-destined images, and you have to do it in 2 stages....

---

## WARNING: **This often results in low quality images**.

- `Image > Image Size` *check* `Resample` and set the `Resolution` to 240PPI. Then click `OK`.
- `Image > Image Size` *uncheck* `Resample` and input the `width` and `height` you want. Then click `OK`.

This *will* get you images at the dimensions you want and the resolution you want. However, **chances are very high that the images will *not* look as good as you think they will.** Doing this often results in degradation of the image overall.

## WARNING: **This often results in low quality images**.

---

While I point out the steps above, you should reexamine the images afterward to ensure they still appear suitable for reproduction. These steps are inherently **bad to perform** on most print-destined images.

Comment: Why the down vote?