# Exporting web design from illustrator to photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, export

I have a website designed in Illustrator that I have exported to PSD, which works okay apart from the fact that it doesn't like clipping paths which I can deal with.

The main issue is that when the design is viewed in Illustrator it's 1024px wide, but when imported into Photoshop it's 4217px wide. I understand Illustrator pixels and Photoshop pixels are not the same. Is there a way to work around this problem?

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Don’t export from Illustrator to a PSD and then import that PSD into Photoshop. Instead, open the Illustrator document in Photoshop and let Photoshop rasterize the image itself. It will pop-up a box where you can set how big you want the pixel image you are creating to be and then create that image within Photoshop.

The export to PSD in Illustrator is for situations where you really want to create a final PSD with Illustrator. Not to move images from Illustrator to Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

To retain the vector qualities of each element, you could *copy/paste* them from Illustrator into your Photoshop document as a **Smart Object**. They can then be resized within Photoshop and double-clicked to edit in Illustrator.

The finality of converting vector to bitmap limits your options for future editing if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the resolution to **Screen (72 ppi)**, from **Photoshop Export Option**, the panel that appear when you try to export your file.[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin, do you think 72ppi will be okay for resolution since we have retina display screens nowadays?

Comment: Yup, I think that will be okay.
I can't tell you exactly because I'm not sure, but I find this http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create-in-200dpi.

Comment: ppi is irrelevant here. All that matters is the pixel dimensions. And yes, you'd want double the pixel dimensions if you want to accommodate retina devices.

Comment: what's your reason for exporting illustrator to photoshop?

Comment: “72 dpi” is not an actual resolution. It is essentially a zero setting on the resolution ruler that tells the application that displays this image to show 1 pixel of the image in 1 pixel of the display.