# My files are re-sizing themselves and I'm unable to change this

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, export

I have created a design in Illustrator with the artboard size of `960px x 350px`.
I have a container for them to fit into but when I save my work either save as, save as web, or expand saving as a PNG. No matter what I do my design changes its size.

My design is to be put into a container using revslider with the same size of `960px x 350px`

Comment: Hi Josh, please don't repeatedly post the same question. Instead, you can [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: What does the size change to? Providing screen shots of the artwork within Illustrator and the resulting export would make your question much more clear.

Comment: sorry for that john first time user

Comment: When you export your design do you have the use artboard checkbox selected?

Comment: @josh Welcome to the site.  Please take a [tour] to understand how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

When you save your file you need to select "USE ARTBOARDS" which is located on the bottom left of the save window (perhaps you'll need to press a small arrow icon to enlarge that window for full view).

Comment: I should add that whether this is the correct answer for you or not - You need to be more specific in your questions. There's a lot of information you could have added to help us figure out what's wrong (especially screenshots)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check the 'ppi' you select while saving the image is 72ppi (Screen). If you select 300ppi (Print), the image will be larger in resolution when viewed on your screen. You can change the ppi when exporting an image.

Comment: This is all assuming the screen you view the image on has a pixel density of 72ppi also.

Comment: This is not true, PPI doesn't matter when viewing images for the web. See [is it mandatory to keep 72 dpi for web design? What if I create in 200dpi?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create-in-200dpi) for an explanation of why. The only time I can think it matters is when saving images for Outlook which uses 94 PPI.

Comment: It depends. Is the image being viewed on the web? Is it being viewed locally? If I view an image on my desktop for example (100px X 100px saved at 72ppi) it will be 100px X 100px. If I save it at a higher ppi such as 144ppi, the image will be 200px X 200px when viewed on my desktop.