# Designing High Resolution Mobile SplashScreens?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mobile

How do you get those stunning splash screens / launch screens for mobile apps? I have tried setting the canvas in Photoshop to be the same pixel size, with 600 PPI, but when I copy my logo for example into the canvas, it looks pixelated, even when I bring it in as a vector and covert to JPEG. I am looking for this sort of thing:

[image: Examples]

I am getting this:

[image: Mine]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPI (Pixels Per Inch) settings generally make no difference to how images are displayed on screen. All that matters is the actual pixel dimensions of the image. As long as you create your document at the full pixel size of the screen then that is all that is needed.

One thing to make sure of is that you are taking in to account the *actual* pixel dimensions. For High pixel density screens this is often higher than you would otherwise think. For example, Retina iPads have a screen size of 2048×1536 not 1024×768.

Although the question is different, the accepted answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create-in-200dpi/13780#13780) is very relevant.

Comment: So how do you get images which look as sharp as the ones shown above, compared with my attempt?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sharp. If your image is the same size then it should 'as sharp'. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: What size (pixel dimensions) is your Photoshop document? It looks quite small. And what device are these images for?