# DPI and resolution

Tags: resolution, dpi

Image below from [article](https://www.scantips.com/no72dpi.html) is 7dpi and 412x324. After reading mentioned article I got understanding that DPI is for printing and pixels is for display. So if I not expect images from web page to be printed I should use lowest DPI, since higher DPI takes more space. I'm right?

[image]

Comment: Please read the article again. Several times if need be.

Comment: Scan high.. save at the width/height you need for the web. see here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-images-at-72dpi-for-web-design

Comment: See the [related meta post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3043/23061) about this topic to help with your understanding as well!

Answer (score 1):

No, no.

There are 3 images. One is at 7 other is at 700. It does NOT matter.

PPI is a little metadata text that electronic mediums, (aka webpage, video) do not use.

Space has nothing to do with it. If you refer to the dimensions, a bigger picture occupies more space than a small one.

If you refer to "weight" or disk space it depends on the compression of the image and the information that the image has. A forest picture has more data than a flat blank white wall's picture, so the second one can compress better.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a duplicate of all the other ppi/dpi tagged questions IMO.

However, the answer to your final question is:

DPI (actually PPI in digital images) is stored as a single number in the header of the file. When a file format actually supports it (I don't think PNG stores PPI), it is most likely only about 1 or 2 byte(s). **So the PPI value has virtually no effect on the file size.**

For a normal photo, the **uncompressed file size is determined almost exclusively by the number of pixels** multiplied by the number of color channels (3 for RGB; 4 for CMYK; add one for alpha channel). So RGB images are usually (width-px * height-px * 3) bytes large.

Two things to note however:

When creating documents, final rendering of typefaces and effects can *potentially* be affected by the document PPI setting.

Some software (usually for-print-oriented software) will prioritize PPI or assume low PPI if it has the flag. This is why placing images in some software makes them appear gigantic.