# Prevent artboard size from doubling if DPI is increased - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png

I want to put a footer in an email. The footer will be 650px wide, and in PNG format.

I am designing the footer in Adobe Illustrator CC. When I go to export, if I export at 72dpi, the outputted file is 650px wide. But the artwork is not crisp.

If I output at 150dpi, the artwork is crisp, but the outputted file is 1313px wide.

Is there a way I can set the art-board to export at 650px width, but 150dpi ?

Comment: DPI/PPI does not exist in email or on the web.

Comment: Doesn't the 150 ppi (as dpi is called nowadays) image just look more crisp because it's bigger and therefore have more details? You can't show more pixels per inch than the screen is capable of.

Comment: Possibly Helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-images-at-72dpi-for-web-design/13780#13780

Comment: Thanks @Scott is there any way to get SVG / EPS like crisp ness in an email footer graphic ? Without having to make the images huge ?

Comment: Vector graphics are rendered to screen using pixels. They stay crisp *when you zoom in*, but they don't look any crisper than an exported PNG when viewed at the same size. There might be some tricks, but it depends a lot on your artwork. Some objects might look better if you let them follow the pixel grid.

Comment: I personally think **any** image in a *communication* email footer is superfluous. Images are for sales emails, otherwise they should not be part of the email as anything other than attachment. There's *no point* in ballooning the file size of communication emails with unnecessary images. If you *must* then SVG is folly.. many email applications won't support SVG at all. Truth is.. anyone using plain text email will see *any* image as an attachment anyway.

Comment: @Scott could I put an `@2x` graphic, in an email and would it display ?

Comment: Look, DPI is not a quality metric. Only the number of pixels matter if your image at 650px does not look crisp it still does not look crisp if you increase dpi but keep the number of pixels! Why? Because its the **same** image.

Comment: If you wrap a 2x image in HTML with a size set, then it'll display **if** the recipient receives HTML email. If the recipient only receives plain text email, it'll be an attachment. Just a personal pet peeve.. I **only** view plaint text email. When someone has an image in a footer, each and every email I get from them has an attachment and I can't tell what's an important attachment or just an egotistical use of an image in the footer. Ask yourself if the image is *really* necessary - in 99.9999% of uses it's not.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, every ppi you change, it will be altered in email view, because the email always tries to show you the image as 72dpi. If you increase the ppi, it will be bigger. The Illustrator is vector based and dpi independent.

Note: ppi(Adobe) and dpi are the same.

The solution is to play with the Anti-aliasing methods while in the PNG options export dialog, and see what is best for you.

I'm showing two examples below.

[image]

Comment: Erm the email app ins showing 72ppi is just showing each pixel as they were presented. Just ignoring your settings entirely.

Answer (score -3):

create a new photoshop document at 150dpi and 650px wide, paste your artwork as pixels in photoshop. Save as jpeg.