# Why does image size decrease when decreasing DPI (resolution) in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, dpi, ppi

I've always known the DPI (or PPI) value and the image size to have an inverse relationship, as the name implies.

For instance, if I have a 500px wide image at 144 DPI, changing it to 72 DPI will increase its dimensions to 1000px wide. I can't recall exactly, but I believe this was my experience with Photoshop in the past. It automatically resized and resampled the image when I changed the DPI value (and had the retain aspect ratio link option selected).

Recently, when I went to the image resizer, I decreased the DPI on some images. To my surprise, Photoshop resized the images automatically, but seemingly in the wrong dimension. It appeared to make them smaller.

Why is this? Gif below.

[image: gif of photoshop image resize by resolution]

Comment: Have you tried unchecking "Resample"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, one should understand that PPI, and subsequently DPI, really only matter for **printing**. They have no real bearing on images destined for the web or displays. PPI of web images doesn't matter. A 500x500px image set to 300ppi or 72ppi, it's still a 500x500px image in a browser. [**SEE HERE**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-images-at-72-dpi-for-web-design/13780#13780)

---

The **Resample** checkbox means *a lot*....

#### With Resample checked:

- Photoshop will add or remove pixels to the image ([interpolate](https://byjus.com/maths/interpolation/)) in order to *maintain* the **physical** width and height and then match the desired PPI. You may start with 30,000 pixels, but after changing the PPI value you will *always* have more or less pixels than that original number. **Resample checked** tells Photoshop that the **physical dimensions** are important and to maintain those by adding/removing pixels.

  - If you make pixels *more dense*, meaning increase the PPI, those original 30,000 pixels will fill *less* space - the *physical* dimensions (w x h) of the image will stay the same. Photoshop must generate *new* pixels through interpolation to supplement the original number of pixels in order to fill the allotted image space. One may think this somehow "improves" image quality. However, because Photoshop interpolates to add new pixels, more pixels do *not* always result in a "better" quality image.
  - If you make pixels *less dense*, meaning decrease the PPI, those original 30,000 pixels will fill *more* space - the *physical* dimensions (w x h) of the image will stay the same. Through interpolation Photoshop *throws away* left over pixels then forces the remaining pixels to fill the desired *physical* dimensions (w x h) of the image - this *always* results in image degradation because you are *throwing away* pixel data.

#### With Resample UNchecked:

- Photoshop attempts to maintain the *same number of pixels* in the image. If your image contains 30,000 pixels, after changing the PPI value, it will *still* have 30,000 pixels. Photoshop will essentially *ignore* the PPI setting for the *pixel dimensions* and keep the original amount of pixels. The *physical* dimensions will change as PPI changes (condensing or expanding the existing number of pixels). **Resample UNchecked** tells Photoshop that the **pixel count** is important and to maintain the *pixel* width and height at all times.

  - When you increase the PPI *without* resampling, Photoshop keeps the **pixel dimensions** of the image the same - there are still only 30,000 pixels. Photoshop then tells those 30,000 pixels to divide by the new PPI value, which will cover *less* space *if printed*. This causes *physical dimensions* of the image to change - more condensed pixels mean the *physical* size must get smaller to hold the 30,000 pixels properly. PPI is irrelevant for web images, there are still only 30,000 pixels, so the pixel dimensions *do not* change.
  - When you decrease the PPI *without* resampling, Photoshop keeps the **pixel dimensions** of the image the same - there are still only 30,000 pixels. Photoshop then tells the 30,000 pixels to divide by the new PPI value, which will cover *more* space if printed. This causes *physical dimensions* of the image to change - less condensed pixels mean the *physical* size must get *larger* to hold the 30,000 pixels properly. PPI is irrelevant for web images, there are still only 30,000 pixels, so the pixel dimensions *do not* change.

---

In short, the **Resample** checkbox tells Photoshop what is *important* - the *pixel dimensions* or the *original image quality* (pixel count).

---

#### The reason you are seeing a size change...

1. Resample is checked
2. The preview is showing the **pixel dimensions** of the image
3. You are decreasing the *total number of pixels* in the image.

If you viewed the *physical* dimensions (inches/cm/mm) you'd see that those dimension are *not* changing. Essentially, the size change for the *pixel* dimensions is a way for Photoshop to tell the user changes will ensue. You are decreasing the PPI, so there are **less pixels** and less pixels means the *pixel* dimensions *must* get smaller.

**Pixel dimensions** are *not* an indicator of quality. Pixel dimensions are merely the size of each pixel in a row set next to one another. Obviously 300px next to each other will create a larger image than 72px next to each other *when printed*.

Sheer *speculation* ..... Really, I think the preview size change is there when PPI changes to actually try and *force* users to question what's going on. If a user is working on a print-destined image, change the PPI, and they see the size change - they stop. Just like you have, and question what's taking place. I speculate it's more of a "fail safe" thing to hopefully make users review the dialog settings. After all, decreasing the PPI for any image destined for *print* is generally an error. For printing, after decreasing the PPI with resample checked, those fewer pixels *must* fill the same *existing **physical** dimensions* of the image - the *printed* image quality *will* be considerably degraded, **if** that's a concern. So the size change is showing the detrimental change in a sort of roundabout manner.

If you want *specific* pixel dimensions for **web images**, change the pixel width or height, don't change the PPI (PPI is irrelevant for web images anyway). Or, if you *do* change the PPI, merely set the *pixel* width and *pixel* height to what you want *after* changing the PPI. Photoshop will interpolate and reorder the pixel data to match the desired settings. This *will* be detrimental to *printing* the image. But you *don't* want Resample checked if you are working on print images.

---

#### When to use either....

For **web** images...

- **Check Resample** and adjust the pixel width or pixel hight to what you need. Ignore the PPI value, it *doesn't* matter. Or change the *pixel* width and *pixel* height *after* altering the PPI. Photoshop will reorder the pixel data to match the desired settings.

For **print** images....

- **UNcheck Resample** and adjust the PPI to what you need. Ignore the *pixel dimensions*, they *don't* matter. **Be aware, it is *not* possible to arbitrarily increase the PPI of any image in order to get a print quality image.**  In order to maintain image quality, you want Photoshop to *not* add or remove pixels (interpolate). You may then need to consider other things due the *physical* width and height changes instigated by any PPI change.

An image destined for *both* ....

- Alter the original image as a print-destined image. That is, keep the high PPI and print size you need for *printing*. Then use `Export..`, `Export As...`, or `Save for Web..` and enter the *pixel dimensions* you want for the image in the subsequent dialog window which opens. That's *why* those features exist. When you adjust the pixel dimensions within one of the dialog windows, Photoshop *does* resample the image as if Resample is *checked* (meaning it interpolates the pixel data), but Photoshop does *not* resample or alter the *original* image - keeping the print quality image still print quality. Essentially, Photoshop interpolates and then "saves a copy" through the `Export...`, `Export As...` or `Save For Web..` dialog windows retaining the original image and its original quality.

---

I think the important *missing* factor in the question may be **why** are you changing the PPI value. For web images, it doesn't matter and you should just use `Export as...` or `Save for Web...`. For print, 72ppi is *always* unacceptable and decreasing the PPI will only degrade the image quality.

If you want the **pixel** dimensions to stay the same when you adjust PPI values.... untick Resample. But then... why change the PPI at all.

If the gaol is to merely "strip away" the extra pixel data at 300ppi... tick Resample, set the PPI to 72, then reset the pixel width and pixel height to what you want after altering the PPI. You'll kill the print quality of the image, but you'll get the web resolution and size you want. It's much easier just to Export or Save For Web (which will do the same thing) rather than degrading the high quality image.

---